# WebView/KitKat Devices/Text auto resizing Issue

Tags: android, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I am working with WebView, and i am getting issue when i am testing my app on KitKat(4.4.2) version devices.

My Issue is:

When i call method findNext(), the text content of Webview gets zoom in and zoom out alternatively.

Please help.

Comment: provide your code for findNext() method and your webSettings

Comment: mWebView.findNext(true);